# Spring Security Oauth2 Customize the number of Attempts

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring-security-oauth2 (1.0.5.RELEASE) and it is working fine.

I would like to customize failed attmepts so that I would log the number of attempts and if it crosses the given number then I will disable the user for say 30 minutes.

How can I achive this? Which classes should I look?

My security configuration is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


<!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<!-- Protected resources -->
<http pattern="/api/**"
      create-session="never"
      use-expressions="true"
      entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<!--  signup dont need access token -->

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="dstest"/>
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="dstest/client"/>
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">      
</bean>



<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/> -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Authentication in config file -->
<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager> -->

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT USERNAME, ROLE FROM USER_ROLES WHERE USERNAME=?" />
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="encoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
</bean>


<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
</bean>

<!-- Token Store  -->
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore"/>

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
    <!-- <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10"/> -->
    <property name="tokenEnhancer" ref="tokenEnhancer"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tokenEnhancer" class="com.mi.common.MyTokenEnhancer"/>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
</bean>

<!-- Token management -->
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                            user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code/>
    <oauth:implicit/>
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:password/>
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                       resource-id="dstest"
                       token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

<!-- Client Definition -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client"
                  authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
                  authorities="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT"
                  redirect-uri="/web"
                  scope="read,write,trust"
                  access-token-validity="3600"
                  refresh-token-validity="36000"/>
</oauth:client-details-service>


<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
</sec:global-method-security>
<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally that kind of functionality would be added to an `AuthenticationManager`. Example (from [Cloud Foundry UAA](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/develop/common/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/identity/uaa/authentication/manager/AuthzAuthenticationManager.java#L101))

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication req) throws AuthenticationException {

  ...

  if (!accountLoginPolicy.isAllowed(user, req)) {
    AuthenticationPolicyRejectionException e = new AuthenticationPolicyRejectionException("Login policy rejected authentication");
    publish(new AuthenticationFailureLockedEvent(req, e));
    throw e;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you see my configuration file, I have two authenticationmanager which one I should modify?

Comment: The one that authenticates users I guess. Or the one that you want to reject failed attempts at any rate. Maybe both of them?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying and found that Implementing AuthenticationProvider also provide solution for this problem.